# Why Kibana reject an Idempotent update operation using PUT

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Recently I use Kibana console to update a field of an existing document in ElasticSearch, I saw this error while using the PUT method for this, which confuse me a lot.

```
{
  "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/product/_doc/1/_update] and method [PUT], allowed: [POST]",
  "status": 405
}
```

The query I used is

```
PUT /product/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc": {"price": 95, "tags": ["Elasticsearch"]}
}
```

Which I believe should be idempotent. Could someone help me understand why only POST method can be used here? My thinking is PUT method is for idempotent operations so to me, PUT should be the only candidate rather than POST.

Comment: simply because the ES update API requires a POST. that's how they decided to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you read the semantics of HTTP a `PUT` would replace a resource entirely and you would need a `PATCH` for an update (which isn't supported by Elasticsearch). Also the `_update` endpoint will either accept `doc` or `script` and the later one isn't necessarily idempotent — for example doing a scripted upsert.

Generally Elasticsearch is as RESTful as possible, but will make pragmatic choices where required.